# Thumb not dragging immediately with wacom board in WPF Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, wacom, stylus-pen

I've created a new WPF application in Visual Studio (.Net 4.5) and just added a Slider to the MainWindow:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="SliderTest.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <StackPanel>
        <Slider />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If I use a Wacom board with Windows Ink enabled and try to drag the thumb, the thumb will be dragged only after a certain noticeable threshold (say 50px).

If Windows Ink is disabled (in the Wacom properties), the thumb is moved immediately as expected.

This problem has been reported also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fac8b98-01c5-4749-abc1-f478e4364802/lag-in-forwarded-mousemove-events-from-stylus-input?forum=wpf) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/291acfcb-612c-4bb6-ba70-239e03491aa2/inkcanvas-lag-on-first-stroke?forum=wpf).

[This issue has apparently been a problem for many Wacom users](http://viziblr.com/news/2013/6/23/the-windows-and-wacom-tablet-nightmare-is-over.html), but for me **it's not an option to disable Ink**.

My understanding is that `Slider` (and `Thumb`) don't handle stylus events directly, but instead "wait" for them to be routed and bubbled and followed by mouse events [see images in this blog post to see the concept illustrated](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html).

Any idea on how to fix the `Slider` behavior with Ink enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a decent fix for `Slider`, so I've decided to build my own custom slider.

In it, I handle mouse and stylus events separately, distinguishing mouse events coming from the mouse from those coming from the stylus by checking if `StylusDevice` is null in `MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer since it's the only answer and after all it solved my problem, but I'll be glad to accept a better one!